# Como interpretar o uso da CPU através do monitor das opções de desenvolvedores do Android?

Tags: android, testes

O Android possui nas suas ferramentas de desenvolvedores a opção para exibir o uso da CPU. Gostaria de saber como interpretá-las? Ou, algum outro *app* que faça o mesmo tipo de serviço para análise do processamento do aparelho.

Comment: Todo aparelho da Samsung possui ao menos um ou dois aplicativos para visualizar o uso da CPU. Alguns launchers também. Existem milhares de apps no Play! que possuem essa funcionalidade também. Mas não sei se existe algo unificado.

Answer (score 2):

Nas opções de desenvolvedor existe a opção "Mostrar utilização da CPU", que exibirá no canto superior direito da tela algumas estatísticas. Na primeira linha há a [**carga média**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_average) do sistema, com três valores representando os **últimos 1, 5 e 15 minutos**. O valor é calculado como o número de vezes que o sistema precisaria se maior para dar conta do recado multiplicado pelo número de núcleos da CPU. Ou seja, se seu aparelho tem 4 núcleos e esse valor mostra `5`, você precisaria ter 5 núcleos para continuar sem que nenhum processo tenha que esperar. A indicação de tempo ajuda a ter uma noção se o uso está crescendo ou diminuindo.

Abaixo há uma lista de processos ativos (os que não estão dormindo ou aguardando por I/O).

Sob cada processo e sob os valores de carga estão três barras que indicam o uso de CPU em cada processo/global do sistema. A parte verde é o uso em [**userspace**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa%C3%A7o_de_usu%C3%A1rio) (o aplicativo está executando o seu próprio código), a vermelha em [**kernel**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa%C3%A7o_de_n%C3%BAcleo) (alguma operação foi delegada ao sistema e o processo está aguardando resposta) e a azul a espera em kernel por leituras ou escritas (similar ao segundo caso, mas aqui o sistema não pode retornar imediatamente e não está realmente processando, apenas aguardando).

Answer (score 1):

As barras coloridas são o tempo gasto por cada processo com espaço de usuário(verde), kernel(vermelho) e entrada/saida(azul). A barra no topo é o gasto total.

Os três números no canto  superior direito são a média de carga - quanto processos havia em média na máquina rodando ou esperando por recurso. Eles representam respectivamente essa média no último **1 minuto**, nos últimos **5 minutos** e nos últimos **15 minutos**. Ou seja, se esses números forem uma ordem crescente (2.5 / 5.0 / 7.5) significa que o CPU foi sendo desocupado nos últimos minutos.

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra boa opção para mensurar o uso de CPU (entre outros) é utilizar do comando:

```
adb shell top -m 10
```